# Sum of numbers in a string

Tags: java, string

I am trying to find the sum of numbers present in the String, but the code runs fine and produce wrong output.

I wrote the below code for the problem:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("System.in");
String s = sc.nextLine();
int sumeven = 0;
int sumodd = 0;
for (int i = 0;i < s.length(); i++) {
    int temp = s.charAt(i);
    if ((s.charAt(i) % 2) == 0) {
        sumeven = sumeven+Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(temp));
    } else if ((s.charAt(i) % 2) != 0) {
        sumodd = sumodd + Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(temp));
    }
}

System.out.println(sumeven + " " + sumodd);
```

Comment: What is the actual result and what is the expected result? 
I see that you compute the sum of the odd and even digits (well digits having odd or even character codes). It doesn't seem to be what your question is about.

Comment: I am printing the sum of odd digits and even digits separately.

Comment: You need to tell us what your input is and what both the expected and actual output are.

Comment: For example, if the input is "430" output should be 4|3. That is the sum of odd numbers and even numbers. .

Comment: Ahh, i see one error now. You need to change `new Scanner("System.in")` to `new Scanner(System.in)`. You want to read from the standard input stream. Not read the literal String "System.in".

Comment: The digit 0 represented as a character has the value 48, your code seems to assume it's 0. That's one problem

Comment: How can I resolve that problem?

Comment: You said numbers, not digits. All digits are numbers but not all numbers are just digits so you need to be specific in your question.  Also, you did not specify if the string could hold non-digits as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are not taking in input from the console but from the string `"System.in"`.
2. You are reading in each character as though it was an `int` which it isn't. Then you are summing each `character` by its parity and giving the wrong result.  For example, the character `S` is represented in ASCII by `83` in decimal. So each character as an `int` for the string `"System.in"` would be `83 121 115 116 101 109 46 105 110` and the sums would be `272 634` which is exactly what you are getting.

So as mentioned in the comments, change to `System.in` to read from the console.

Then you need to parse the line looking for an actual number like `25` in `"abc25def"` and then convert to an `int` and sum those based on parity.

One way is to use a [regex](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile(java.lang.String)) to extract the numbers from a string.

```
String line = "abc10def21 ghijll 49sks12";
Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(s).results()
      .forEach(mr->System.out.println(mr.group()));
```

prints

```
10
21
49
12
```

To sum up the odd and even numbers you can stream the values, convert to an `Integer` and then [group](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) them by parity and put in a map.  The sum is computed using [Collectors.reducing](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing(T,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)). Using the `line` from above:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(s).results()
        .map(mr -> Integer.valueOf(mr.group()))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                v -> v % 2 == 1 ? "Sum of Odds" : "Sum of Evens",
                Collectors.reducing(0, (a, b) -> a + b)));
map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
Sum of Odds=70
Sum of Evens=22
```

If you are only summing digits, then you don't need a regex and can just do it like this.

- stream the characters using `chars()`
- filter out non digits and convert to `Integers`.
- Then group as before.

```
Map<String, Integer> sumDigits = s.chars()
        .filter(Character::isDigit)
        .mapToObj(Integer::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                v -> v % 2 == 1 ? "Sum of Odds" : "Sum of Evens",
                Collectors.reducing(0, (a, b) -> a + b)));
sumDigits.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
Sum of Odds=204
Sum of Evens=200
```

Answer (score 0):

Using java streams you find the sum of numbers in string like below

```
 String s= "String123";
 Integer sum = IntStream
                    .range(0, s.length())
                    .filter(i -> Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)))
                    .map(i -> Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i)))
                    .sum();
 System.out.println(sum); // output will be 6
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use new Scanner(System.in) instead of new Scanner("System.in").
this code should works.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        int sumeven = 0;
        int sumodd = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            int temp = s.charAt(i) - '0';
            if (temp % 2 == 0) {
                sumeven += temp;
            } else {
                sumodd += temp;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sumeven + " " + sumodd);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if a character isn't a digit?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).